# glm/glm.hpp file not found in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, compiler-construction, glm-math

Other answers seem to have some relevant information, but nothing that fixes the problem I'm having.

From my project in Xcode, I chose 'add files to project' and selected the entire glm sub-folder (which I have been told is all you need to use glm). Then, in my `main.cpp` file, I wrote `#include glm.hpp` to receive the error `glm/glm.hpp` file not found from the `glm.cpp` file.

Has anyone else had this problem? It is supposedly a header-only library, which means I dont have to add any include paths, right?

Comment: Try putting your glm stuff into a '/glm' folder and `#include "glm/glm.hpp"` from your main.

Comment: @dari doesn't seem to be the problem, still same error as before.

Comment: Btw. Header-only library does not mean that you don't have to add any include paths. The include paths tell the compiler where to find files that are included with `#include`.

Comment: @dari True, however using include paths unfortunately didn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update "Header Search Path" in xcode to include your "glm-0.9.5" directory.

```
Project->Build Settings->Search Paths->Header Search Paths
```

( In my case, I have added "/Users/me/work/glm-0.9.5" )

Comment: I tried doing that, didn't work. Then I tried again after reading this, and it worked. Not quite sure what I did wrong the first time, but in any case it went smoothly the second time. Thanks!